# Replace the content of a certain dead area of the display

Tags: touch

There's an area on the quarter top of my touch that is not working. Dead.
The display works on that area, the touch doesn't

I know I can disable the touch and image on that area, dragging everything closer to the bottom

But

Is there a way to do that, and instead of leaving a useless black area, display some information in there (that doesn't require touch) ?

I have Xposed

XMultiWindow is a cr@p

Aindroid M

Answer (score 0):

Using xposed edge you can extend input:
From one working edge you can go halfway in direction of the broken part and a crosshair will move the double (or more, based on config) distance in the same direction.
Releasing finger will fake a tap under the crosshair.

Xposed edge require xposed framework, installation procedure for the framework depends on device and system installed, most of the time only require working recovery that is able to install non OEM signed archives.

Comment: Thank you. That app is of great aid. Will stick to it if nothing closer to the optimum arises. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is the module *Dimensions Editor*, for Xposed

Using that, I could make the status bar larger than the dead area, helping a little